# Is sine related to circle or curve?

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

As tangent is a line passing through a curve in one point, and secant is a line passing through a curve in two points, is sine also something like this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean with the start of the sentence but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine especially the section "relation to the unit circle"

Comment: The word "tangent" is re-used between trigonometry and calculus. They are related but not the same.

Comment: Your Question needs clarification.  The word "sine" is thought to come down to us from Latin *sinus*, meaning opening.  The sine of an angle is related to the chord length subtended by a central angle in a circle.

Comment: The re-use of the words "tangent" and "secant" from plane geometry as the names of trigonometric functions is a source of confusion. I think this question illustrates the reason for the confusion rather well, and merits an answer.

Answer (score 4):

In plane geometry, the words "secant" and "tangent" can be adjectives applied to a line that intersects a circle.
A "tangent line" just barely *touches* the circle (hence *tangent,* from a Latin word for *touching*).
A "secant line" *cuts through* the circle (hence *secant,* from a Latin word for *cutting*).

There are also (in trigonometry and calculus) *functions* named "secant" and
"tangent". The *secant* of an angle $\theta$ is written $\sec(\theta)$.
It is the length of the line segment indicated by the double-headed arrow
next to which $\sec\theta$ is written in the figure below.
The *tangent*  of an angle $\theta$ is written $\tan(\theta)$.
It is the length of the line segment indicated by the double-headed arrow
next to which $\tan\theta$ is written in the figure below.

It so happens that the line segment labeled $\tan\theta$ in the figure
is part of a tangent line of the circle, and the segment labeled $\sec\theta$
is part of a secant line of the circle.
(The figure shows only one segment of the secant line, intersecting the circle once, but if you draw the rest of the line it will intersect the circle again in the lower left part of the figure.)

The sine function is also the length of a line segment in the figure;
it is labeled $\sin\theta$. But there is no such thing as a "sine line" relative to the circle. In fact, if we draw the rest of the line on which the $\sin\theta$ segment lies, we can see that it's just another secant line.

In summary, "secant line" and "tangent line" describe entire lines in relatively generic ways; they also describe all possible ways in which lines can intersect a circle. The sine, tangent, and secant *functions,* in contrast, can be interpreted geometrically, but only as the *lengths* of specific *line segments.*

[image: sine, secant, tangent on a unit circle]

Answer (score 0):

Tangent has two meanings:

1. The $\tan: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ function.
2. A straight line that intersects a curve at one and only one point.

The $\sin$ function represents the $y$-coordinate of a point on a circle.

Comment: As tangent have two meanings does sine also have two meanings apart from a function?

Comment: @Kartik https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_(disambiguation)